# Reference: the number of smooth structures on a topological $n$-manifold, $n\geq 5$ is finite

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am looking for a reference of the following result, that I read a while ago in a book but I cannot remember where:

> Any (compact?) $n$-manifold, $n \geq 5$, has a finite number of smooth structures. In other words, if $M$ is a topological manifold, there exists a finite number of homeomorphic, non-diffeomorphic smooth manifolds $M_{1}, \ldots, M_{k}$ such that $M$ is homeomorphic to all of them and any smooth structure on $M$ is equivalent to the one of some $M_i$.

Maybe $k$ coincides with the number of smooth structures on $S^n$, but I cannot remember the whole statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement you refer to is a theorem of Kirby and Siebenmann; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2128026/39599) for more information.

As for your last statement, the number $k$ is not always equal to the number of smooth structures on $S^n$. For $n \geq 5$, the number of isomorphism classes of smooth structures on $T^n$ is in one-to-one correspondence with $H^3(T^n; \mathbb{Z}_2)$; see [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/239162/21564). Therefore $T^n$ has $2^{\binom{n}{3}}$ smooth structures, while the number of smooth structures on $S^n$ is much more complicated, as discovered by Kervaire and Milnor; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere#Order_of_%CE%98n) and [here](https://oeis.org/A001676).

For example, $T^5$ has $2^{10} = 1024$ different smooth structures, while $S^5$ has only one.

Answer (score 4):

There are not really as many structures on $T^n$ as that: typically one mods out $H^3(T^n;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ by the action of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z}/2)$.  This is discussed by Wall in chapter 15A of Surgery on Compact Manifolds.  In fact up to diffeomorphism there are 3 smooth structures on $T^5$. It's important to also credit Hsiang-Shaneson here.

Nonetheless, $T^n$ does have multiple smooth structures up to diffeomorphism, for all $n \geq 5$, and typically much more than $S^n$ does, so the general idea behind the answer is correct.

The answer also missed the action of the group of homotopy spheres $\Theta_n$ on the set of diffeomorphisms classes of smooth structures on $T^n$. This is a nontrivial action when $\Theta_n$ is nontrivial, which does not change the corresponding element of $H^3(T^n;\mathbb{Z}/2)$. So the exotic spheres also give rise to exotic tori.

Hsiang, Wu-chung; Shaneson, Julius L. "Fake tori." In: 1970 Topology of Manifolds (Proc. Inst., Univ. of Georgia, Athens, Ga., 1969) pp. 18–51 Markham, Chicago, Ill.

Comment: I have done this, thanks.